# Error installing mongoose on Linux

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, npm

I'm using centos 6.6, npm 2.14.4

If I try and install mongoose with the following..

```
npm install --save mongoose
```

It comes up with lots of compile type errors, looks related to kerberos ?

Example output...

```
> kerberos@0.0.15 install /home/ian/node/nodeapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/ian/node/nodeapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
In file included from /home/ian/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node.h:42,
                 from ../lib/kerberos.h:4,
                 from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:
/home/ian/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:336: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/ian/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::MaybeLocal::MaybeLocal()’:
/home/ian/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:353: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
...lots more similar errors
```

Any thoughts on whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have mongodb installed correctly via the package manager, installed via [centos mongo install](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/)